# Screen flickering in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: display, night-light

I have weird screen flickering both with redshift and the night mode in Ubuntu 22.04. Whenever the light starts changing, the screen starts flickering from time to time.

This is the `sudo lshw -c video` output

````
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       produit: TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q]
       fabricant: NVIDIA Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:01:00.0
       nom logique: /dev/fb0
       version: a1
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration : depth=32 driver=nvidia latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       ressources : mémoireE/S:600-5ff mémoireE/S:600-5ff irq:141 mémoire:6f000000-6fffffff mémoire:6000000000-600fffffff mémoire:6010000000-6011ffffff portE/S:4000(taille=128) mémoire:70080000-700fffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       produit: CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics]
       fabricant: Intel Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 2
       information bus: pci@0000:00:02.0
       nom logique: /dev/fb0
       version: 05
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration : depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       ressources : mémoireE/S:600-5ff mémoireE/S:400-3ff irq:140 mémoire:6012000000-6012ffffff mémoire:4000000000-400fffffff portE/S:5000(taille=64) mémoire:c0000-dffff```
````

Comment: Flicking is often a sign of a wrong driver. You asked a video question with no idea what graphics card or driver you are using.

Comment: I use NVIDIA GTX 1650 and Intel UHD graphics. I've added the ```sudo lshw -c video``` output

Comment: Please never show pictures of text,. Cut and paste the text into the body of the question. Makes it easier to read, can be searched and does not get cut off.

Comment: Still missing info what card is the monitor attached to?

Comment: it is a laptop. I assume it's using the NVIDIA card ?

Comment: I’m not sure if this is anything to do with it, but I had a flickery screen when ‘automatic screen brightness’ (in settings / power) was enabled. Presumably whatever was trying to sense ambient light (I guess the camera) may not be behaving on my 12 year old laptop. I prefer setting it manually anyway!